# Htaccess 301 redirect with wildcard to separate sections

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect past incoming links to new sections because a client has renovated there site.

e.g.

```
 http://www.asite.co.uk/news540.html
```

to

```
 http://www.asite.co.uk/category/news
```

also

```
 http://www.asite.co.uk/topichome.html
```

to

```
 http://www.asite.co.uk/topic-homepage/
```

In the first example I want to catch any incoming links that contain news prior to the html with the number being a wild card.
In the second one I want to catch specific topics and redirect them to the new topic homepage.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first scenario, something like this should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^news([0-9]+)\.html$ http://www.asite.co.uk/category/news [R=301,L]
```

This rule will "catch" any newsXXXX.html and redirect it (301) to /category/news (where XXXX is any number).

For the second scenario:

```
RewriteRule ^topichome.html$ http://www.asite.co.uk/topic-homepage/ [R=301,L]
```

This is much simpler. pageA.html is redirected to pageb.html.

Note that in both rules:
left url is the original one, from root
right url is the "final, redirected" one